# when i run my apps "Verify your internet connection Flutter"

Tags: flutter

when i run my app

Verify your internet connection Flutte

How can fixed, please!!

[image]

Comment: You need to add a lot more information to this question. It looks like you created the SnackBar in your app and determined what goes there. Share your code if you can.

Comment: share your code please to be your question more clear?

Comment: can help me how can i Share my code ?

Comment: i am new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\android_intent-0.3.7+2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\androidintent\MethodCallHandlerImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.5\android\src\main\java\io\f`enter code here`lutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62333/YmH-U3mbZts=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/FlutterFcmService( 4128): Fatal: failed to find callback
D/EGL_emulation( 4128): eglMakeCurrent: 0x9eb861a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9eb83720)
I/flutter ( 4128): {app_name: , default_tax: null, default_currency: null, currency_right: false, enable_paypal: true, enable_stripe: true, enable_razorpay: true, mobile_language: en}
I/flutter ( 4128): Error in (initSettings (package:ecommerce/src/repository/settings_repository.dart:42:36)) | [<html>
I/flutter ( 4128): <head>
I/flutter ( 4128): <META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow">
I/flutter ( 4128): <script src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3">
I/flutter ( 4128): </script>
I/flutter ( 4128): <body>
I/flutter ( 4128): </body></html>
I/flutter ( 4128): ]
```